# FileZilla handling internet interuptions

Tags: sftp, filezilla

So as I am moving a large amount of data using `filezilla` with `sftp`, I will be experiencing network cut offs in between the transfers.

So in the case I am unplugging the cable myself, do I uncheck the `Transfer` > `Process Queue` to stop it temporarily?

If network is cut off suddenly, will `filezilla` be able to handle that and re transfer what is failed during that cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after using the app I find that it can indeed handle interruptions well.

Whatever goes into the failed list can be redone. And you can stop it too to change the internet before resuming.

But do keep in mind that anything that is midway transferred being stopped will be restarted completely.